# C# Authorization & Consistent Validation w/ PHP

Tags: c#, php, validation, authorization

So I've made a simple C# application and I'm currently using HTTPrequests to login to my phpBB forum, using a custom PHP file to check the post count of the user, and consistently resends HTTPrequests every 30 seconds. Unfortunately, I fear that this can easily be cracked despite the obfusculation. I've heard of serialization, but I don't know what that is.

Any suggestions for consistently validating the post count/login or optimizing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that may help:

1. Are these on the same server or different servers? PHP has solid built in COM support, so there is no reason to use any kind of sockets if they are on the same server.
2. I can think of two options here: (a) Provide no authentication and make the data such that if someone gets it there is no downside (b) encrypt the data / authentication yourself.

(b) may be easier than you think. PHP has solid built in encryption:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$key = "ThisIsYourKeyOfDoomAndPower";
$encryptedData = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $dataToEncode, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
```

Hopefully this helps you get on the right track...

Answer (score 0):

First of all serialization is not a method to protect your code. You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

The problem you may likely have is that you may pass your forum credentials in insecure way (without SSL/TLS encryption). This way anyone using a HTTP sniffer can get that data with little effort. If you are worried that someone may decompile your app and steal your code then there are some ways of making that harder (like obfluscation that you've mentioned) but you can never be 100% safe.

If I'm missing the point here please provide more details about your app vulnerability.